# Type/Annotate text on screen

Tags: 14.04, compiz

How can I type text on screen, similar to Compiz Annotate, but for text. I end up hand drawing text on the screen along with annotate sometimes but it looks pretty bad/amateur. I found the [Text plugin library](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/ImageLoading#Text) but don't see any plugins that make use of it. Does something like this exist?

Comment: Is the question still up ?

Comment: Yes, it still needs an answer.